# iOS 8 sound for app doesn't work like it did in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone

I developed my game app in Xcode 5.1.1. Yesterday i downloaded Xcode 6.1.1. in Xcode 6.1.1 when i upload any of the iOS 8.1 simulators the sound doesn't work. However, sound works perfectly fine for all iOS 7 simulators. I'm using AudioToolbox.framework for my .aiff sounds. Is there a coding difference between iOS 7 and iOS 8 apps? Or is it something else?

in my ViewDidLoad, code for sound...

```
 NSURL *SwishURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"SwishSound" ofType:@"aiff"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SwishURL, &SwishID);
```

Comment: IIRC you will need to test this on a device, not in the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with audio, but with a little searching I found a working solution that works in Xcode 6.1.1 [here](http://raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18819).

The implementation is like this:

```
@import AudioToolBox;
@import AVFoundation;

NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound_effect" ofType: @"wav"];
NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
AVAudioPlayer *sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:nil];

[sound play];
```